# sending an email in php to an address stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

I am trying to send an email with PHP, but I want the recipients to be an email which is stored in my database.

Here is some code

```
$send  = $mailer->setTo('email@example.com', 'Your Email')
                 ->setSubject('Example')
                 ->setFrom('example@email.com', 'test')
                 ->addMailHeader('Reply-To', 'example@test.com', 'test')
                 ->addMailHeader('Cc', 'edonaghy--@hotmail.co.uk', 'test')
                 ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
                 ->setMessage($message)
                 ->setWrap(400)
                 ->send();
```

Here is the email which is being send, its pullin in from a form which the user fills out

```
mysql_select_db("lr", $con);
require 'mail/class.simple_mail.php';
$mailer = new SimpleMail();

$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];
$time = $_REQUEST['time'];
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$place = $_REQUEST['place'];

$message = "<strong>This is an email from the bride to you the bridesmaids, here is the information on the next dress fitting<br />Date:".$date."<br />Time: ".$time."<br /> Place:".$place."<br />Any other comments: ".$comments." </strong>";
if ($send) {echo 'Your Email has been sent';}else {
echo 'An error occurred. We could not send email';
```

Comment: Ok so you have some code to send the email. Do you have any code which connects to and queries your database?

Comment: First thing would be to put valid data into this and test it. That will already indicate whether the mailing process works well. Then you will need to write some code to fetch data from database. If you get stuck with that code, just come back and show it to us so that we can help.

Comment: Yeah i tested it and it works when just sending to a mnually inputted email.

Comment: So you're trying to query data from a database.. do it then. You're not saying what errors are happening, you're basically asking us to program for you, it doesn't work like that. We can give you hints if you can tell us what the actual problem is.

Comment: In your second code block, where is `$send` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query your database. Please have a read of this tutorial for mysqli http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

You will need something like this.

```
$qry = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username = ?'"
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
$stmt->bind_param('s', 'someone'):
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($email);
```

And then put $email in the setTo parameter.

This tutorials better actually. http://codular.com/php-mysqli